# PHP Trait using another trait, calling a method from the used trait

Tags: php, traits

I have a MyTranslatable trait, which uses another OtherTranslatable trait, the one from a third party package. I'm including them as follows.

```php
trait MyTranslatable
{
    use OtherTranslatable {
        OtherTranslatable::method as public otherTranslatableMethod;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Perform my actions

        // Call otherTranslatableMethod
        static::otherTranslatableMethod();
    }
```

I'm wondering if this is valid, the code is working but I'm not so sure if traits are meant to be used this way, and if this is the correct way to call the "parent trait's" method like this after my actions are complete

Comment: Sure, that's valid.

Comment: It may be valid, whether it is appropriate Is disputable, but theres not enough context to tell. But probably not, traits are rarely appropriate. Traits mean multiple inheritance, multiple inheritance means violation of SRP...

Answer (score 1):

I think your code from architectural point of view is correct since child blueprints (classes, traits) in PHP can override in `use` statement of the context, the methods from already used traits (I avoid call this inheritance because using trait is actually copy-paste), but I don't find quite necessary to invoke your `otherTranslatableMethod()` statically in `MyTranslatable` (of course except if it's defined as static in `OtherTranslatable` trait).

If you have non-static definition of `OtherTranslatable->method()` you can do the following in order to make your code more correct and clean.

```
trait MyTranslatable
{
    use OtherTranslatable {
        method as public otherTranslatableMethod;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Perform my actions
        // Call otherTranslatableMethod
        $this->otherTranslatableMethod();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.